# Kdenlive VFR to CFR

Tags: transcoding, keyframes, kdenlive

When using videos taken on my phone (Pixel 4a) kdenlive reports variable framerate and asks to transcode with several options,

- Lossless (huge files)
- Intermediate DNxHR HQ (large files)
- x264 I frame only

How does I-frame only work? If it really is only keyframes, then wouldn't the output would be a 1 fps slideshow? Are frames interpolated or dropped?

Discussion

- https://www.reddit.com/r/kdenlive/comments/un4njd/what_is_exactly_is_to_transcode_videos_and_is_it/
- https://discuss.kde.org/t/transcoding-clips-due-to-vfr-samsung-s21settings/4784